# Upgrade Problem with libc6

Tags: 14.04, package-management

Running 14.04.4 LTS.  apt-get upgrade bombs silently when I install remotely and I've isolated it to the libc6 package.  From my shell ...

```
# apt-get install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 140 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,696 kB of archives.
After this operation, 18.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc6-dev amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 [1,910 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 [69.0 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc6 amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 [4,717 kB]
Fetched 6,696 kB in 0s (7,991 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 106509 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev_2.19-0ubuntu6.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) over (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc-dev-bin_2.19-0ubuntu6.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) over (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) over (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
#
```

Everything looks fine here that I can tell however, at the console I see this and it spams no matter what I type.

```
General error mounting file systems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system.
Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):
```

If I Control-D it reboots and persists.  If I enter root password quickly enough on console, I get a shell but then it spams out and keyboard becomes non responsive and then I get logged out.  Otherwise system seems "normal" from the remote shell.  I'm hesitant to continue with this system in the current state and I can revert back to the snapshot but I'm concerned that this is coming from an apt update and upgrade -- I have over a dozen other systems just like it and they all have the same packages requiring upgrade.

Also, if I run the update/upgrade from the console it happens right at the completion and spams the error and maintenance mode message with every keypress.